# Returning some null values from a collection

Tags: c#, linq, null

I have a LINQ query, I need to return all the customers in our database, however not all of them have a middle name. This is my query:

```
select new 
{
        firstName = a.firstname,
        middleName = a.middlename,
        lastName = a.lastname,
};
foreach(var c in queryAccount) 
{    
    console.writeline(c.firstname);
    console.writeline(c.middlename);
    console.writeline(c.lastname);
}
```

What I am looking for is something similar to:

```
if (c.middlename != null)
{
    console.writeline(c.middlename);
}
```

Does anyone know how I could get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use [Null Colaescing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx)  operator:-

```
select new {
        firstName = a.firstname,
        middleName = a.middlename ?? String.Empty,
        lastName = a.lastname,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Rahul's answer is correct. Additionally in case you don't want to assign 'middleName' at all you can do:

```
Select(x =>
            {
                var obj = new TestData
                {
                    Lastname = x.Lastname,
                    Firstname = x.Firstname
                };
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Middlename))
                    obj.Middlename = x.Middlename;
                return obj;
            });
```